# Interactively reading from and writing to command line with UI application

Tags: c#, command-line

I have UI app that calls cmd periodically with different arguments and I want to periodically update UI with cmd output results.
Here's the code I use, but the problem is that UI is updated only when all commands are executed and not after each command and I didn't find solution for periodic update of UI when each command is executed:

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    };
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();

    var reposToUpdate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateAndMergeReposOnBranch"];
    foreach (XmlNode repoPathNode in reposPaths)
    {
        var repoPath = repoPathNode.Attributes["root"].Value;
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("cd {0}", repoPath));
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"hg update --check");
        p.StandardInput.Flush();
    }

    p.StandardInput.Close();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    rtbOutput.Text = output;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of using the `Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` method:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();

// Output handling:
p.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
p.BeginOutputReadLine();

var reposToUpdate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateAndMergeReposOnBranch"];
foreach (XmlNode repoPathNode in reposPaths)
{
    var repoPath = repoPathNode.Attributes["root"].Value;
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("cd {0}", repoPath));
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"hg update --check");
    p.StandardInput.Flush();
}

p.StandardInput.Close();
```

In the example above all data printed to the `Console`. Alternatively you can append output to the TextBox:

```
p.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => rtbOutput.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => rtbOutput.Text += e.Data));
```

Please note that you should also handle the [`Process.Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: not good: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rtbOutput' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @kobac use the [`Control.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) for cross-thread operations. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `BeginOutputReadLine` method and associated event to receive data as it happens in the process.

```
p.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
p.BeginOutputReadLine ();
p.WaitForExit();
```

then elsewhere add a method

```
void OnOutputDataReceived (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   // DO Something with the output
}
```

there is also a `ErrorDataReceived` event that will hook to `stderr`.